# Get a user's profile using AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, openid-connect, google-oauth, aspnet-contrib

recently I've spent some time digging into [AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server). I use [MVC sample](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Samples/tree/master/samples/Mvc) as a code base for my client/server apps.

The thing I need to implement now is obtaining a user's profile info from an external provider (Google) and saving the info into the server's database.

What is the right place for getting and saving a profile's info and a proper way to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: since ASOS (`AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server`) only handles the OAuth2/OpenID Connect server part, it's actually not involved in the authentication part, and thus doesn't directly deal with the external providers you configure.

To achieve what you want, the best approach is to configure the Google middleware to extract more information from the user object returned in the user profile response and to persist them in the authentication cookie so you can later retrieve them in your application code.

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(options => {
    options.ClientId = "client_id";
    options.ClientSecret = "client_secret";

    options.Events = new OAuthEvents {
        OnCreatingTicket = context => {
            // Extract the "language" property from the JSON payload returned by
            // the user profile endpoint and add a new "urn:language" claim.
            var language = context.User.Value<string>("language");
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:language", language));

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
});
```

[image: You can retrieve the urn:language claim from the User instance]

If the response doesn't include the data you need, nothing prevents you from using `context.Backchannel` to make another HTTP call to retrieve more data from a different Google endpoint.